# Showing/hiding a ProgressBar after clicking on a custom adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-progressbar

There's a way in which I can call and modify the visibility of the ProgressBar from my main layout on the adapter?

I need to call a web service after an item was clicked, this to show to the user something is happening.

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, count;
    public ImageView overflow;
    public View colorView;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        colorView = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.colorView);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //progressBar from the layout
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();

                prepareToSendLog(itemPosition);


            }
        });


    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out. Sounds exactly like what you need: https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment

Answer (score 1):

You could add a member to MyViewHolder class to hold a reference to the ProgressBar from your main activity. Set this in the MyViewHolder constructor when you instantiate MyViewHolder from the main activity.

I added that to your class here:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;   <<<======== ADDED

    public TextView title, count;
    public ImageView overflow;
    public View colorView;
    public MyViewHolder(View view, ProgressBar bar) { <<========= here
        super(view);
        mProgressBar = bar;                     <<=============== and here
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        colorView = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.colorView);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //progressBar from the layout
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();

                prepareToSendLog(itemPosition);


            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand completely what do you mean "this to show to the user something is happening."

Basically you have two options:
1) You can set a progress bar in each item in your recycleview/listview and show it whenever user clicked on it. In that case you should check Mike solution
2) You can add a progress bar to your main layout where you have your recycleview than when the user click on the item you change the visibility of recycleview and progressbar (you will hide the recycle view while showing the progressbar) and fetch the data. When the data is fetched you should ether go to other screen activity/fragment or just show the user the details of the items.

From what I see in your code I think you thought of doing it like the second option.

Your layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_dummy"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"


         >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your adapter will get the click listener from the activity/fragment

**Adapter**

```
     public class MyRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycleViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>
    {
        private List<Data> mData;
        private View.OnClickListener    mItemClickListener;

    public MyRecycleViewAdapter(List<Data> data, View.OnClickListener listener)
    {
        mData = data;
        mItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public MyRecycleViewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

        return new MyRecycleViewAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecycleViewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Data data = mData.get(position);

        //here you will put all details about the item in the item layout

        //this is most important part, here you basically save the index of the clicked item and will get the item itself in the clickListener in your fragment/activity. check the other function after the adater
        holder.mRootView.setTag(position);
//you put the clicklistener event to the root layout of your item layout
        holder.mRootView.setOnClickListener(mItemClickListener);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public Data getItem(int position)
    {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        @BindView(R.id.item_root_layout)
        public View mRootView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

**Now the fun part in the activity/fragment**
The activity/fragment should implement the View.onClickListener interface.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.item_root_layout:
                // here we are retriving the index out of the tag of the 
                // selected item
                int selectedSeriesIndex = (int) view.getTag();
                Data selectedItem = mAdapter.getItem(selectedSeriesIndex);

                recycleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //fetch your data here

                break;
        }
    }
```